# System of Six Equations, Line Conic Degeneration and Decomposition

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, systems-of-equations, conic-sections

If we have the line conics
\begin{align}
\Sigma & \equiv \mathscr{A} l^2 + \mathscr{B} m^2 + \mathscr{C} n^2 + 2 \mathscr{F} m n + 2 \mathscr{G} n l + 2 \mathscr{H} l m = 0 \\
\Sigma' & \equiv \mathscr{A}' l^2 + \mathscr{B}' m^2 + \mathscr{C}' n^2 + 2 \mathscr{F}' m n + 2 \mathscr{G}' n l + 2 \mathscr{H}' l m = 0
\end{align}
then we can choose $\lambda$ such that the pencil of line conics $\Sigma + \lambda \Sigma' = 0$ is degenerate, it will factor into a point-pair: $$(A l + B m + C n) (A' l + B' m + C' n) = 0$$ If we expand this equation, we get $$A A' l^2 + B B' m^2 + C C' n^2 + (B C' + C B') m n + (A C' + C A') n l + (A B' + B A') l m = 0$$ Then we see that the six coefficients $A, B, C, A', B', C'$ are given by the system of six equations\begin{align}
 A A' & = \mathscr{A} + \lambda \mathscr{A}' \\
 B B' & = \mathscr{B} + \lambda \mathscr{B}' \\
 C C' & = \mathscr{C} + \lambda \mathscr{C}' \\
 B C' + C B' & = 2 (\mathscr{F} + \lambda \mathscr{F}') \\
 A C' + C A' & = 2 (\mathscr{G} + \lambda \mathscr{G}') \\
 A B' + B A' & = 2 (\mathscr{H} + \lambda \mathscr{H}')
\end{align}
How do I go about solving this system for $A, B, C, A', B', C'$? None of my owned calculators can do it. They run out of resources. I tried solving it by hand but after writing multiple pages I am afraid I will make a mistake and it will all go to waste. If it is not possible to gift me the solutions, is there any easy way to solve this system?

A range of conics has three point-pairs, so there should be three different solutions to the equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
 A A' & = \mathscr{A} \tag1\\
 B B' & = \mathscr{B}\tag2\\
 C C' & = \mathscr{C}\tag3 \\
 B C' + C B' & = 2 \mathscr{F}\tag4 \\
 A C' + C A' & = 2 \mathscr{G} \tag5\\
 A B' + B A' & = 2 \mathscr{H}\tag6
\end{align*}

From $(1)(2)(3)$,
$$A'=\frac{\mathscr{A}}{A},\quad B'=\frac{\mathscr B}{B},\quad C'=\frac{\mathscr C}{C}$$

Substituting these into $(5)(6)$ gives

$$(5)\implies \frac{C^2}{A^2}\mathscr{A}  - 2\mathscr{G}\frac CA +\mathscr C=0\implies \frac CA=\frac{\mathscr G\pm\sqrt{{\mathscr G}^2-\mathscr A\mathscr C}}{\mathscr A}:=p$$

$$(6)\implies  \frac{B^2}{A^2}\mathscr{A} -2\frac BA \mathscr{H}+\mathscr B =0\implies \frac BA=\frac{\mathscr H\pm\sqrt{{\mathscr H}^2-\mathscr A\mathscr B}}{\mathscr A}:=q$$
giving $$B=qA,\quad C=pA$$
Substituting these into $(4)$ gives
$$q\frac{\mathscr C}{p}+p\frac{\mathscr B}{q}=2\mathscr F\tag7$$

So, as a result, the system has solutions 
$$(A,B,C,A',B',C')=\left(r,qr,pr,\frac{\mathscr A}{r},\frac{\mathscr B}{qr},\frac{\mathscr C}{pr}\right)$$
where $r\not=0$ is a real number and
$$p=\frac{\mathscr G\pm\sqrt{{\mathscr G}^2-\mathscr A\mathscr C}}{\mathscr A},\quad q=\frac{\mathscr H\pm\sqrt{{\mathscr H}^2-\mathscr A\mathscr B}}{\mathscr A}$$ if and only if $(7)$ holds.

Comment: This is the solution I almost posted. However, it's problematic if $\mathscr{A} = 0$, so I was going to apply a normalization condition, such as $$\mathscr{A}^2 + \mathscr{B}^2 + \mathscr{C}^2 +\mathscr{F}^2+\mathscr{G}^2+\mathscr{H}^2= 1$$ with similar for $A$, $B$, $C$ and $A^\prime$, $B^\prime$, $C^\prime$. At that point, though, things got a little out of hand. :)

Comment: @Blue: Nice catch. I admit that I deliberately ignored that case. :)

Comment: This answer is great! Do you have any idea why my calculator was unable to do this? Also, if I factor the conic instead into $\rho (A l + B m + C n) (A' l + B' m + C' n)$ then it would it be right to say $r = \rho$?

Comment: @DavisRash: For the first commet, no, I don't. For the second, no, it wouldn't. Since we have $\rho AA'=\mathscr A,\rho BB'=\mathscr B$ and so on, we can replace $\mathscr A$ with $\frac{\mathscr A}{\rho}$, $\mathscr B$ with $\frac{\mathscr B}{\rho}$ and so on. So, the solutions are $(A,B,C,A',B',C')=(r,qr,pr,\frac{\mathscr A}{r\rho},\frac{\mathscr B}{qr\rho},\frac{\mathscr C}{pr\rho})$ where $r\not=0$ is a real number and the same $p,q$.

Comment: @mathlove Is it possible to solve this system in a similar way if, say, $\mathscr{C}$ = 0?

Comment: @DavisRash: Sure. Why don't you set $\mathscr C=0$ in the solutions?

Comment: @DavisRash: See Blue's comment above. My answer gives the solutions for the cases where $\mathscr A\not=0$. (For $\mathscr A=0$, the system becomes simpler, so it is not so difficult to deal with that case.) If $\mathscr A\not=0$, then you can use the solutions safely, of course for the case where $\mathscr C=0$. I hope this helps.

Comment: @Blue How does the normalization condition work? Is 1 an arbitrary number?

Comment: @DavisRash: $1$ is basically arbitrary, but it's the best choice. :) Sum-of-squares normalization is a way of saying "Not all of these things can be zero." (Squaring prevents negatives from canceling positives.) Eg, in a line equations $ax + b y + c = 0$, we can't have $a=b=0$ (although $c$ can be anything); we *normalize* the equation by dividing through by $s:= \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ to get $a^\prime x + b^\prime y + c^\prime = 0$, where $a^\prime = a/s$, etc. Notice that $(a^\prime)^2 + (b^\prime)^2 = (a/s)^2 + (b/s)^2 = (a^2+b^2)/s^2 = s^2/s^2 = 1$. [continued]

Comment: Normalization also helps deal with coefficient ambiguity that accompanies our ability to multiply-through an equation by any (non-zero) value we like. $3 x + 4 y + 100= 0$ represents the same line as $6x+8y+200=0$ or $30x+40y+1000=0$, so it's unwise to directly compare coefficients of two equations (as you do in your conic equation and factored form). But, there is *only one* normalized equation for that line; namely, $(3/5)x+(4/5)y + 20= 0$ (obtained by dividing-through by $\sqrt{3^2+4^2}$). Only this equation for that line has a sum-of-squares norm of $1$. This kind of specificity is useful.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, there isn't a solution in all cases; there's only a solution if the original conic is, in fact, degenerate.  The most you could hope for is to end up with some condition(s) on the original coefficients which tell you that the conic is degenerate.  As you might already know, this condition is that the [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_conic#Discriminant) of the conic (the determinant of a certain 3 by 3 matrix of the coefficients) is zero.  But the determinant is messy if written out in full, so even in the case when there is a solution, I don't expect there would be a nice "formula" in terms of the original coefficients, if that's what you were hoping for.

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit the question for clarification. The conic definitely is degenerate because I chose $\lambda$ such that the discriminant of the pencil of conics is 0.